# Symfony full page in Redis cach

Tags: php, symfony, redis

I know we can store items from db in Redis, but it is possible to store rendered full page in Redis cache?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think so. You can render the page in a controller/service and pass it to Redis, there's a documentation snippet that shows how to render a Twig template and save the results in a variable:

```
// src/Service/SomeService.php
namespace App\Service;

use Twig\Environment;

class SomeService
{
    private $twig;

    public function __construct(Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        // ...

        $htmlContents = $this->twig->render('product/index.html.twig', [
            'category' => '...',
            'promotions' => ['...', '...'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

You can then use [Cache Contracts](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html#cache-contracts) (assuming you have configured [Redis Adapter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/redis_adapter.html)) to get/set rendered page from cache.

If you would wish to render it, you might want to return retrieved page in `Response` object in desired controller.